# C++ linker error

Tags: c++

I"m having some problem with the following program. The program implements a stack using a linked list. I'm not showing all my code here because the code is fine. But the problem I'm having is with linking different files together.

I'm using an IDE to run the program. When I run the `TestIntStacks.cpp`, the main method is  supposed to call `test()` from `StackFunctions.cpp`. The test function (defined in `StackFunctions.cpp`), uses the `TestStack` class methods.
Currently I'm receiving an error saying "linker error, push/pop not defined". What I'm doing wrong? I'm sure it's something to do with a namespace.

```
MyStack.h
-------------------------------------
namespace A
{
    class Node{
        public :
            char data;
            StackNode* link;
            StackNode(int v=0): data(v), link(NULL){ }
    };

    class MyStack{
        private:
            Node * top;

        public:
            MyStack():top(NULL){ }
            void push(int c);
    };
}//namespace


//TestStack.cpp
--------------------------------------------------------------
#include "MyStack.h"

namespace A
{
    void MyStack::push(int x)
    {
        StackNode *temp = new StackNode(x);
        temp->link = top;
        top = temp;
    }
}

//StackFunctions.cpp
-----------------------------------------------------------
#include <iostream>
#include "TestStack.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace A;

void test()
{
    MyStack st;
    st.push(1);
    st.push(2);
    st.push(3);
    st.push(4);
}

// TestIntStacks.cpp
----------------------------------------------------------------
// Code for testing the TestStack
// from the A namespace.

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
#include "TestStack"
#include "StackFunctions.cpp"

void test();
int main()
{
    test();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not sure if it's about namespace. Showing how you build the program and how you use this class in StackFunction.cpp may help people help you.

Comment: You've got an error, you assume your code is fine.  It's not.  Give us your code so we can tell you where in your code it's wrong.

Comment: What is the linker command?  send what the linker runs

Comment: I'm using DEV-C++ IDE. I'm running the TestIntStacks.cpp file

Answer (score 1):

You are defining `push()` and `pop(`) methods in your header file TestStack.h, but you've not provided implementations for them in TestStack.cpp.  You need to add the code that does the push and pop operations on your object.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've implemented them in my TestStack.cpp file, I just didn't show my code here. The program works fine when it's in one file, when it's not separated into .h and .cpp files. I'm using dev-c++ IDE.

Answer (score 1):

This error seems pretty clear to me. You declared `push()` and `pop()` in your header file, but the linker could not find where these methods are implemented.

Where are they defined?

Comment: they are defined int the TestStack.cpp file. I'm not showing the code inside the methods since it is a homework problem. The program works fine when it's in one file but when I separate it into .h and .cpps it gives error. Thanks so much

Comment: One way or another the linker cannot find them. Either they are undefined, they were not defined correctly, or the file that defined them is not getting linked in correctly. You've provided no information to help me determine which. (BTW, it's interesting that you would post this error without showing your implementation of the methods mentioned in the error.)

Comment: @user623629 Now your header doesn't even define the method pop(), which is part of the error. Sorry, this is too much work for me. Read my previous comment carefully. The answer's there somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I think it has to do with the arguments provided to linker. For example, a similar error occurs when you use Visual C++ 6 in a following way. Let's say you created .cpp and .h files for a class. If you do not include cpp file into your project you get the similar error. Because the IDE does not determine the source file based on the provided header file. I don't know about dev-c++ IDE, but the solution might be similar. The problem is you compile (or not) TestStack.cpp and the output of this compiling is not provided to the linker, so the linker can't find the implementation.

Comment: You might be right because when I include the .cpp files in my TestIntStacks.cpp file then the program works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to force the build script to use both cpp files.  If you wrote your own make file, you need to build intermediate objects for each source, and then link at the end.

I suspect DEV-C++ doesnt automatically generate object files or try to link everything together.

Comment: stupid question: did you create a project?  If so, there should be some project settings that let you choose which files are to be compiled as object files.